# How to get the sum of value of field

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

After getting the data from db I want to count the value of **outcome** field

The Dummy Data :

```
[
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("62ebc7b037292c87fbb44b7a"),
      uniqueID: '6303246862620',
      sn: 'N400W150726',
      transactionAmount: '0157213',
      currencyCode: '9000000058800',
      terminalId: '05000001',
      transactionDate: 2022-06-17T00:00:00.000Z,
      transactionTime: +151539-12-31T23:00:00.000Z,
      transactionType: 'TRANSACTION_TYPE_PURCHASE',
      cardPAN_PCI: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX166',
      onlineRetrievalReferenceNumber: '6551151112',
      outcome: 'OUTCOME_APPROUVED',
      encryptionKeyKCV: '65465112213',
      transactionEncrypted: 'SUHTHROTRTH161461'
    },
{
      _id: new ObjectId("62ebc7b037292c87fbb44b7a"),
      uniqueID: '6303246862620',
      sn: 'N400W150726',
      transactionAmount: '0157213',
      currencyCode: '9000000058800',
      terminalId: '05000001',
      transactionDate: 2022-06-17T00:00:00.000Z,
      transactionTime: +151539-12-31T23:00:00.000Z,
      transactionType: 'TRANSACTION_TYPE_PURCHASE',
      cardPAN_PCI: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX166',
      onlineRetrievalReferenceNumber: '6551151112',
      outcome: 'OUTCOME_DECLINED',
      encryptionKeyKCV: '65465112213',
      transactionEncrypted: 'SUHTHROTRTH161461'
    },
{
      _id: new ObjectId("62ebc7b037292c87fbb44b7a"),
      uniqueID: '6303246862620',
      sn: 'N400W150726',
      transactionAmount: '0157213',
      currencyCode: '9000000058800',
      terminalId: '05000001',
      transactionDate: 2022-06-17T00:00:00.000Z,
      transactionTime: +151539-12-31T23:00:00.000Z,
      transactionType: 'TRANSACTION_TYPE_PURCHASE',
      cardPAN_PCI: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX166',
      onlineRetrievalReferenceNumber: '6551151112',
      outcome: 'OUTCOME_DECLINED',
      encryptionKeyKCV: '65465112213',
      transactionEncrypted: 'SUHTHROTRTH161461'
    },{
      _id: new ObjectId("62ebc7b037292c87fbb44b7a"),
      uniqueID: '6303246862620',
      sn: 'N400W150726',
      transactionAmount: '0157213',
      currencyCode: '9000000058800',
      terminalId: '05000001',
      transactionDate: 2022-06-17T00:00:00.000Z,
      transactionTime: +151539-12-31T23:00:00.000Z,
      transactionType: 'TRANSACTION_TYPE_PURCHASE',
      cardPAN_PCI: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX166',
      onlineRetrievalReferenceNumber: '6551151112',
      outcome: 'OUTCOME_DECLINED',
      encryptionKeyKCV: '65465112213',
      transactionEncrypted: 'SUHTHROTRTH161461'
    }
  ]
```

I want to get something Like this

```
[
  { name: 'OUTCOME_APPROUVED', value: 1 },
  { name: 'OUTCOME_DECLINED', value: 3 }
]
```

I tried this code but doesn't return anything

```
let logs = await Promise.all(
  tpes.map(async (item) => {
    return await this.logModel.aggregate([
      { $match: { terminalID: item } },
      { $group: { _id: { _id: '$outcome' }, count: { $sum: 1 } } },
    ]);
  }),
);
```

// OUTPUT logs[ ] ==> nothing, does the index doesn't work with **$match** ? 
Once I change the function to this

```
let logs = await Promise.all(
      tpes.map(async (item) => {
        return await this.logModel.find({terminalId})
      }),
    );
```

I got data but can't group it use the $sum function to count the value of field I want

Answer (score 0):

You need to simply group by `$outcome` like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      terminalId: "05000001",
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$outcome",
      "value": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "name": "$_id",
      "value": 1,
      "_id": 0
    }
  }
])
```

Here's the playground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/P2xHITIy0Z_).

Comment: the data i got from multiple docs so i need to match the data with dynamic variable

Comment: Data will be from multiple docs, but what about the key, will the key also vary in docs

Comment: but data should selected by an Id i'dont want to get all data should be filtred by an id

Comment: you can add a $match before grouping

Comment: variable 'item' in my question contain an array I want loop the array and each index I want to match it

Comment: Is this a node js problem? Because things are working as expected in mongodb

Comment: Also what are the elements of your array